# Show splash screen instantly after system is powered

Tags: startup, init-script, u-boot, yocto, bootsplash

I would like to execute a command instantly after system is powered. My project is realized in an embedded Linux environment (Yocto-based, with U-boot bootloader), therefore I would like to show a splash screen -almost instantly after powered- on a framebuffer, which involves:

- Initializing display driver (modprobe command)
- Export an environment variable (to set up framebuffer for QT)
- Displaying a picture on the screen (QT app)(or any more viable suggestion?)

Now, I know psplash helps to display some logo in the boot screen, but that is not what I'm trying to accomplish. What I want is to show this image on a framebuffer (and not on the display that X11 is connected to) whilst the bootloader is loading.

I already have an initscript recipe in Yocto which accomplishes setting up my main application using `update-rc.d myapp 10 90 defaults`. However, this happens after boot, naturally.

Is there any way to simply do what I'm trying to accomplish here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a TFT display which I want to run with framebuffer, I don't have another display but X11 is forwarded to HDMI, so I can make use of that in the future. However, I want to display splash screen on TFT with framebuffer, then run my app on it. Nothing with the other display.

Guidance on running u-boot splash screen / psplash on framebuffer is also appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Yocto, but with `grub2` based systems a package to look for would be something like `splash` or `splashscreen` (I can't remember offhand).

Comment: I think you said that you have two displays, but I am not sure. Can you proof read and make it clear?

Comment: I just added a note. I hope it helps

Comment: Are you looking for Plymouth? https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/

Comment: Hi, for the splash screen, that is nice to have, yes. But I really do have to execute that modprobe command to fire up my TFT display. Also, im not sure how initramfs will work, will it replace my rootfs which I already have?